# Checking a SQL Azure Database is available from a c# code

Tags: azure-sql-database

I do an up scale with a code like this on an Azure SQL Database:

ALTER DATABASE [MYDATABASE] Modify (SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S1');

How is it possible to know from a c# code when Azure has completed the job and the table is already available?

Checking for SERVICE_OBJECTIVE value is not enough, the process still continue further.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of performing this task in T-SQL I would perform the task from C# using an API call over to the REST API, you can find all of the details on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163571.aspx).

Specifically, you should look at the [Get Create or Update Database Status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt643934.aspx) API method which allows you to call the following URL:

```
GET     https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{server-name}/databases/{database-name}}/operationResults/{operation-id}?api-version={api-version}
```

The JSON body allows you to pass the following parameters:

```
{
    "id": "{uri-of-database}",
    "name": "{database-name}",
    "type": "{database-type}",
    "location": "{server-location}",
    "tags": {
        "{tag-key}": "{tag-value}",
        ...
    },
     "properties": {
        "databaseId": "{database-id}",
        "edition": "{database-edition}",
        "status": "{database-status}",
        "serviceLevelObjective": "{performance-level}",
        "collation": "{collation-name}",
        "maxSizeBytes": {max-database-size},
        "creationDate": "{date-create}",
        "currentServiceLevelObjectiveId":"{current-service-id}",
        "requestedServiceObjectiveId":"{requested-service-id}",
        "defaultSecondaryLocation": "{secondary-server-location}"
    }
}
```

In the properties section, the `serviceLevelObjective` property is the one you can use to resize the database. To finish off you can then perform a GET on the [Get Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt643935.aspx) API method where you can compare both the `currentServiceLevelObjectiveId` and `requestedServiceObjectiveId` properties to ensure your command has been successful.

**Note:** Don't forget to pass all of the common parameters required to make API calls in [Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163571.aspx#sqlrestcommon).